# Trying to solve $2\log_{5x+9}(x+3)+\log_{x+3}(5x+9)=3$ without seeing the obvious solution

Tags: logarithms, contest-math

> Determine all real values of $x$ such that $$\log_{5x+9}(x^2+6x+9)+\log_{x+3}(5x^2+24x+27)=4$$

<sub>Taken from Waterloo 2012: [Link](http://www.cemc.uwaterloo.ca/contests/past_contests/2012/2012EuclidContest.pdf)</sub>

What I tried:

$$2\log_{5x+9}(x+3)+\log_{x+3}\left((x+3)(5x+9)\right)=4$$

$$2\log_{5x+9}(x+3)+\log_{x+3}(5x+9)=3$$

Then I was stuck and I graphed it:

[image]

It was clearly $0$:

$$2\log_{9}(3)+\log_{3}(9)=3$$

But how could I do it without seeing the "zero"? Is there a way?

Comment: **Hint:** Use $$\log_ab = \frac{\ln b}{\ln a}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve

$2\log_{5x+9}(x+3)+\log_{x+3}(5x+9)=3$

first of all we note that

$$\log _a b=\frac{1}{\log _b a}$$

the equation becomes

$$2\log_{5x+9}(x+3)+\frac{1}{\log_{5x+9}(x+3)}=3$$

And then set $w=\log_{5x+9}(x+3)$

$2w+\dfrac{1}{w}=3\to 2w^2-3w+1=0\to w_1=\dfrac{1}{2};\;w_2=1$

If $w=1$ we have $\log_{5x+9}(x+3)=1$ which means $5x+9=x+3\to \color{red}{x=-\dfrac{3}{2}}$

If $w=\dfrac{1}{2}$ then $\log_{5x+9}(x+3)=\dfrac{1}{2}$

that is $(5x+9)^{1/2}=x+3$

$5x+9=(x+3)^2\to x^2+x=0\to \color{red}{x=0;\;x=-1}$

Let's verify these solutions in the given equation

for $x=0$ we have $2\log_{9}(3)+\log_{3}(9)=3\to 2\cdot \frac12+2=3$ true

for $x=-1$ equation becomes $2\log_{9-5}(3-1)+\log_{3-1}(9-5)=3\to 2\log_4 2+\log_2 4=3$ true

and for $x=-\dfrac{3}{2}$ we have $2\log_{9-\frac{15}{2}}\left(3-\frac32\right)+\log_{3-\frac32}\left(9-\frac{15}{2}\right)=\log_{\frac{3}{2}}\left(\frac12\right)^2+\log_{\frac12}\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)=3$

Hope this is useful

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $$\log_{5x+9}(x^2+6x+9)+\log_{x+3}(5x^2+24x+27)=4$$
$$\log_{5x+9}(x+3)^2+\log_{x+3}\left[(5x+9)(x+3)\right]=4$$
$$2\log_{5x+9}(x+3)+\log_{x+3}(5x+9)+\log_{x+3}(x+3)=4$$
$$2\frac{1}{\log_{x+3}(5x+9)}+\log_{x+3}(5x+9)+1=4$$

Now, substitute $u=\log_{x+3}(5x+9)$ and solve the quadratic equation for $u$.

Note that we need to assume $x+3>0$ and $5x+9>0$.

Comment: i think $$\ln(x+3)^2=2\ln|x+3|$$

Comment: why can we assume this?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner: To prevent a negative base of the logarithm?

Comment: ok this is an argument

Answer (score 0):

To complete @MrYouMath

$2u+\frac{1}{u} = 3$

where $u = \log_{5x+9} x+3$

$u = 1$ or $u = \frac{1}{2}$

Case 1: $u = 1$

$x+3 = 5x + 9$

$x = -\frac{3}{2}$

Case 2 : $u = \frac{1}{2}$

$(x+3)^2 = 5x+9$

$ x^2+x = 0$

$x = 0$ or $x= -1$

All three values are greater than $x = -3$ and $x = -\frac{9}{5}$

Answer (score 0):

HINT.-

$$\log_{5x+9}(x+3)^2=X\iff (5x+9)^X=(x+3)^2\\
\log_{x+3}(5x+9)=Y\iff(x+3)^Y=5x+9$$ It follows $(x+3)^{XY}=(x+3)^2$.

Consequently $X+Y=3$ and $XY=2$ which produces $X^2-3X+2=(X-2)(X-1)=0$ From which the solution.